# I wanted to connect android studio to mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I wanted to insert data in mysql and also to retrieve, modify and delete rows in it. I don't have any programming knowledge, just a little database manipulation. This android studio is a whole new thing for me and its like i'm having problems from the tutorials regarding on connecting android studio to  mysql. I tried to use the ip add of my computer, the 10.0.2.2 , the 127.0.0.1 and even registering for a free web hosting but it still doesn't insert data.

Another thing the dialog box that should display the status of registration doesn't work.

One last thing I know that the mistake is in this code because when i looked on their tutorial it worked but i can't figure it out why it doesn't work on me.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

here's the php file

```
conn.php
<?php
$db_name = "dbapp";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="";
$server_name="localhost";
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);
?>


register.php
<?php
require "conn.php";
$f_name=$_POST["first_name"];
$m_name=$_POST["middle_name"];
$l_name=$_POST["last_name"];
$email_add=$_POST["emailadd"];
$user_name=$_POST["username"];
$user_pass=$_POST["userpass"];

$sql_query = "insert into tbluser (f_name, m_name, l_name, user_emadd, user_name, user_pass) values('$fname','$mname','$lname','email_add','$user_name','user_pass')";
?>
```

here's some of the android studio files

Register.java

```
package com.example.*****.myapplication;
// Above code is not really asterisk, i just wanna hide it..
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Register extends Activity{

    EditText ET_FNAME,ET_MNAME,ET_LNAME,ET_EMAIL,ET_USERNAME,ET_PASS;
    String txtfname, txtmname, txtlname, txtusername, txtemail, txtpass;


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    ET_FNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_fname);
    ET_MNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mname);
    ET_LNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_lname);
    ET_EMAIL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    ET_USERNAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    ET_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

}


public void userReg(View view){

    txtfname = ET_FNAME.getText().toString();
    txtmname = ET_MNAME.getText().toString();
    txtlname = ET_LNAME.getText().toString();
    txtemail = ET_EMAIL.getText().toString();
    txtusername = ET_USERNAME.getText().toString();
    txtpass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();


    String method = "register";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(method,txtfname,txtmname, txtlname, txtemail, txtusername,txtpass);
    finish();

}
}
```

here's another java class
BackgroundWorker.java

```
package com.example.*****.myapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;

BackgroundWorker(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/myapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/myapp/login.php";

    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String fname = params[1];
        String mname = params[2];
        String lname = params[3];
        String emailadd = params[4];
        String username = params[5];
        String userpass = params[6];

              try {
                   URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                   OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                   BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                   String data = URLEncoder.encode("f_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                   URLEncoder.encode("m_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                   URLEncoder.encode("l_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                   URLEncoder.encode("email_add", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailadd, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                   URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                   URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userpass, "UTF-8");



                  bufferedwriter.write(data);
                   bufferedwriter.flush();
                   bufferedwriter.close();
                    OS.close();
                   InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                   IS.close();

                  httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return "Registration Success";


} catch (MalformedURLException e)
                          {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IOException e)
                          {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }

    }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate (Void...values){
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if(result.equals("Registration Success"))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
     }
    }
}
```

here are the column name in mysql, it has userid as primary key and autocrement.

```
 fname
 mname
 lname
 email_add
 user_name
 user_pass
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-Injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Please start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: What do you mean connecting android studio to mysql? Android studio is an ide for android apps.

Comment: i want other device to also access the database.. its like i'm going to insert data in my device to update the database while the other device will see the changes done.